# Request_logs on Google App Engine - append erases for new version?

Tags: google-app-engine

I set up a cron job to download the logs using the following code:

```
echo [password] | appcfg.py request_logs --num_days=1 --severity=0 --append --passin --email=[user] --quiet /tmp/code/ ~/site_logs/`date +%m-%d-%y`.txt
```

I run it every 5 minutes, which is great for having the latest logs available to grep through.  However, if I bump the version number, the log doesn't seem to honor append.  It just writes over the file.

Am I missing something?  Is there a better way to get this to continuously dump the logs to disk?

Comment: I couldn't reproduce your problem. What version of the sdk are you using? I tried with 1.6.6

Answer (score 0):

If you're still having this problem, you could expose a minimal API to expose the current version id and query that before fetching. It's hacky but it works.

The currently serving version ID can be retrieved using os.environ['CURRENT_VERSION_ID']. See: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/runtime